# Pemanantl storage value and also increment innangular using storage key or session storage

Tags: angularjs

I am generate ticket id but one ticket id also for one user and second user take new ticket id it is increasing privious ticket id

I am use sessionstorage but when new user login ticket is.   also Take inialition value and i want new value